# Streaming-download a gzipped file from s3 and unzip it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, zlib

I was trying to download a gzipped file from s3 bucket using AWS-SDK and then unzip the file using Zlib.

Here is my code for this part:

```
File.open('app/assets/data.xml.gz', 'wb') do |file|
  bucket.objects['linkshare_temp/data.gz'].read do |chunk|
    file.write(chunk)
  end
end


Zlib::GzipReader.open('app/assets/data.gz','rb') do |gz|
  File.new("data.xml", "w") do |g|
    IO.copy_stream(gz, g)
  end
end
```

It gives me this error:

```
Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format
```

The file was downloaded from s3 to my local disk. I can see the file in my local folder with the right name and "xml.gz" suffix, but for some reason I can not open that file. I think there is something wrong with my code for downloading from s3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you manually examined the contents of the downloaded file?

Comment: I tried to unzip the downloaded file manually. But i get some file with xml.gz.cpgz suffix. dont know why

Comment: Consider the possibility that it may have been transparently unzipped, on the fly, during the download, if the file has `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the S3 metadata.  Remove the .gz extension and see what you have.  Compare sizes, use a hex editor, that sort of thing.

Comment: I just checked the size of it. It's zero bytes so it was not even successfully downloaded. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. I also tried removing the .gz extension but it still gives me an empty file.